# Convergence of sequences of random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable. Show that $\frac{X}{n}$ converges to zero in probability and almost surely, as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I am sort of confused by this question since I only learnt a definition of convergence for a sequence of random variables. Am I reading something wrong ?

Comment: @user1952009 Not sure this is even *related*.

Answer (score 2):

In thise case, the sequence of random variables is given by $X_n = \frac{X}{n}$. You just need to apply the definition of convergence in probability resp. almost sure convergence to solve this exercise.

Comment: I understand. thank you for the clarification

Comment: Could you show me how to do that ? I just want to use this as an example